# is there a way to access a value from a nested dict and update value in the same dict based on searching a list?

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
dict_1 = {'key1': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 203, 'soft_DN': nan}}
{'key2': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 204, 'soft_DN': nan}}

A_list = [2031111, 2031112, 2031113, 2042222, 2042223]
```

My goal is to search A_list to locate the first integer that starts with 203 and 204,(2031111 and  2042222) and update the respective soft_DN value.

Updated dict should look like this:

```
dict_1 = {'key1': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 203, 'soft_DN': 2031111}}
{'key2': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 204, 'soft_DN': 2042222}}
```

Comment: Using dict.items() will get you the key, value pairs.  You can then search and update them using for loops.

Answer (score 3):

First your dict is not formatted correctly, I suppose it's supposed to look like this:

```
dict_1 = {'key1': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 203, 'soft_DN': None},
      'key2': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 204, 'soft_DN': None}}
```

The simple way of doing this would be converting the numbers to strings then comparing the first 3 chars to the `dn_range`

```
>>> int(str(2031111)[:3])
203
```

That said I don't know how large your dataset is and if it is pretty large you'd want to save time by reducing how many times you loop through the list as your iterating the dict. To do so I suggest using `itertools.groupby` to get a dict of keys being the first 3 digits of the integers and the values being the first integer that shows. That said make sure your integers are grouped together by fist 3 chars otherwise you'll need another way of doing this.

```
from itertools import groupby
ranges = {int(k): next(v) for k, v in groupby(A_list, key=lambda i: str(i)[:3])}
```

---

Result:

```
{203: 2031111, 204: 2042222}
```

Then just loop through the dict and replace the values

```
for k, d in dict_1.items():
    d['soft_DN'] = ranges.get(d['dn_range'])
```

---

Result:

```
{'key1': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 203, 'soft_DN': 2031111}, 'key2': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 204, 'soft_DN': 2042222}}
```

Comment: I like this solution. To make sure the integers in the list are grouped together, you can sort the list before creating `ranges`.

Comment: @NanoTellez I thought of that, although sorting may affect how OP wants the list sorted/arranged thus possibly affecting/changing the first value.

Comment: This actually works for me, except I neglected to mention that the dict values could be duplicated.. so for example, 
'key2': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 204, 'soft_DN': None
'key7': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 204, 'soft_DN': None

in this case I would like to assign the first available in the list to key 1, so 2042222 -- and key7 should be assign the next available 204 in the list. Thanks for your help

Comment: @NanoTellez et al, thanks for the feedback! I used pieces of each, along with sorting the dataframe prior to converting to dict + calling the iter function on list. I ended up with:

A_list  = iter(A_list )
for key, value in dict_1 .items():

    for item in A_list:

        if str(item).startswith(str(value['dn_range'])):

            value['soft_DN'] = item
            break

Answer (score 0):

This code below will work as you wish:

```
dict_1 = {'key1': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 203, 'soft_DN': -1}} 
dict_2 = {'key2': {'Type': '51', 'dn_range': 204, 'soft_DN': -1}}

A_list = [2031111, 2031112, 2031113, 2042222, 2042223]

for i, x in enumerate(A_list):
    #Get rid of unnecessary part
    x = str(x)
    x = x[:3]
    x = int(x)

    if x == dict_1["key1"]["dn_range"] and dict_1["key1"]["soft_DN"] == -1:
        dict_1["key1"]["soft_DN"] = A_list[i]    
    
    if x == dict_2["key2"]["dn_range"] and dict_2["key2"]["soft_DN"] == -1:
        dict_2["key2"]["soft_DN"] = A_list[i]

print(dict_1, dict_2)
```

- Firstly I have separated the two dictionaries into `dict_1` and `dict_2`.
- Then with the first three lines in for loop I am getting rid of the unnecessary part of the number (since we only want to check the first three digits)
- Then I am checking key `'dn_range'`. If the number matches it - then rewrite `-1` to the first good number.

Comment: If the answer helped you please leave a thumbs up! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "first integer in A_list..." means the first index (as opposed to the smallest, in case the list is not sorted), then you can loop through the dictionary and search the A_list for each entry in the dict:

```
for key, entry in dict_1.items():
    dn_range = entry["dn_range"]
    for dn in A_list:
        if dn_range * 10000 <= dn < dn_range + 1 * 10000:
            entry["soft_DN"] = dn
            break
```

If A_list is sorted, then you can do a binary search to find the target dn value instead of going through the list one by one. This will speed up your algorithm considerably.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no magic here in Python. I would just:

- Iterate over the entries of `dict_1` and for each entry:

  - Get the `dn_range` field
  - Iterate over the items of `A_list` and for each item:

    - Check whether the item starts with `dn_range` (string representations can help here, strings have a `startsWith()` method) and, if so:

      - Update the dict entry and `break` out of the list iteration loop.

Python loops are much like pseudo code loops, easy to write and read. You will love them!
Hints:

```py
for key, value in dict_1.items():
```

```py
for item in A_list:
```

```py
if str(my_item).startsWith(str(d_range)):
```

Enough hints, happy coding!